# X509CertificateHolder constructor not accepting the X509CertificateStructure as argument

Tags: java, javascript, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I am quite new to java programming and I still strugling with some things. I am trying to implement a bouncycastle certUtils with some customizations. however the X509CertificateHolder constructor is accepting the X509CertificateStructure as argument. the compiler keep suggesting me to change return type of the function that generates the structure to byte[]. Refusing in this case the X509CertificateStructure as argument. this under normal circumstances should not happen since the X509CertificateHolder has a constructor that accept X509CertificateStructure. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk16/1.46/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder.java#X509CertificateHolder.

here is the code where is error happens.

```
 static X509CertificateHolder  generateFullCert(ContentSigner signer, TBSCertificateStructure tbsCert)

 {
    try
     {


         return  new X509CertificateHolder((generateStructure(tbsCert, signer.getAlgorithmIdentifier(), generateSig(signer, tbsCert)))); // the error occurs here
     }

     catch (IOException e)

     {

         throw new IllegalStateException("cannot produce certificate signature");

     }

   }

 private static X509CertificateStructure    generateStructure(TBSCertificateStructure tbsCert, AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId, byte[] signature)


 {


     ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();



     v.add(tbsCert);

     v.add(sigAlgId);
     v.add(new DERBitString(signature));



     return X509CertificateStructure.getInstance(new DERSequence(v));

 }
```

Does anyone has an idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: please in case the question is too easy and I have to read some staff. I will be happy to have any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using another version of *bouncycastle* jars in your project rather than mentioned 1.46.
E.g. *bcpkix-jdk14-**1.50**.jar* offers only the following constructors for `X509CertificateHolder`:

```
/**
 * Create a X509CertificateHolder from the passed in bytes.
 *
 * @param certEncoding BER/DER encoding of the certificate.
 * @throws IOException in the event of corrupted data, or an incorrect structure.
 */
public X509CertificateHolder(byte[] certEncoding)
    throws IOException
{
    this(parseBytes(certEncoding));
}

/**
 * Create a X509CertificateHolder from the passed in ASN.1 structure.
 *
 * @param x509Certificate an ASN.1 Certificate structure.
 */
public X509CertificateHolder(Certificate x509Certificate)
{
    this.x509Certificate = x509Certificate;
    this.extensions = x509Certificate.getTBSCertificate().getExtensions();
}
```

which looks more like what your compiler is suggesting to change to.